# Ember.js with Rails 3.1 getting error "Unable to find template"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to setup [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com) with Rails 3.1 and I'm getting the following error in the Firebug console:

```
uncaught exception: Error: <(subclass of App.ListOrdersView):ember201> - Unable to find template "app/templates/orders/list".
```

I followed [this guide](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/01/26/beginning-ember-js-on-rails-part-2). Here is my manifest file, which correctly loads all the js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require vendor/ember
//= require vendor/ember-rest
//= require_tree ./../lib
//= require app/app
//= require_tree ./../app/models
//= require_tree ./../app/controllers
//= require_tree ./../app/views
//= require_tree ./../app/helpers
//= require_tree ./../app/templates
//= require_self
```

This is the handlebar template app/templates/order/list.handlebars:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each orders}}
    {{view App.ShowOrderView orderBinding="this"}}
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Rails view file app/views/orders/index.html.haml

```
%script{:type => "text/x-handlebars"}
  = hb 'view App.ListOrdersView'


:javascript
  $(function() {
    App.ordersController.loadAll(#{@orders.to_json.html_safe});
  });
```

Finally the gems for Ember.js, in Gemfile:

```
# Ember
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'hamlbars', :git => "https://github.com/jamesotron/hamlbars.git"
gem 'rasputin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use either `ember-rails` or `rasputin`, but using both gems together might lead to unpredictable behavior. Since they both attempt to register and precompile your handlebars templates, they are redundant in purpose but their usage differs.

If you look at the readme for `rasputin`, you'll see that templates get registered without `templates` in their path. Therefore, if you want to use this gem, you'll need to declare your template as `app/orders/list` instead of `app/templates/orders/list` in `App.ListOrdersView`.

Comment: Great! I have removed both rasputin and ember-rails and added [emberjs-rails](https://github.com/jamesotron/emberjs-rails), changed `app/templates/orders/list` to `app/orders/list`, and it works. Don't have a clue why it works this way.

Comment: I guess emberjs-rails also strips the word "templates" from paths when registering them. Any particular reason you went with this gem over ember-rails / rasputin? Just curious, I haven't tried it.

Comment: I tried with using rasputin alone, as you suggested, with no luck. I don't know, I may have missed something. embers-rails works so I went with that :)

Answer (score 1):

check the paths, maybe they should be

```
//= require_tree ./app/models
//= require_tree ./app/controllers
//= require_tree ./app/views
//= require_tree ./app/helpers
//= require_tree ./app/templates
```

Unable to find template app/templates/order**s**/list

This is the handlebar template app/templates/order/list.handlebars:

see the path difference in **s**

Comment: The manifest file is in `app/assets/javascripts/admin`, while the Ember.js `app` folder is in `app/assets/javascripts`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues when changing template definitions and ember gems. Although the error was the same (complaining about the template path - even though the paths all seemed correct), all it took was a `rake assets:clean` to get things sorted out.